# Go into the wrapper of bygone time

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

I wrote this sentence -

> Now I can’t see those custom. They seem to have gone into the wrapper of bygone time.

Do you think "go into the wrapper of bygone time" works here? I didn't find any reference, so may be I am the first one to write this. So native speakers, do you think it's understandable?

What I wanted to mean -
"go into the wrapper of bygone time" = "go into past"

Comment: Are you trying to say that you don't see those customs observed anymore, that they were only observed in the past? (Note the plural "customs", by the way.)

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I am trying to say. (good catch, "customs". Thanks)

Comment: I think this is an Off Topic request to comment/improve on OP's creative writing. FWIW, *belong to the past* might work, but it's not necessarily any better or any worse than many alternatives.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could it be rewritten to say: "Am I using the phrase 'gone into the wrapper of bygone time' correctly in this sentence?"

Comment: @godel9: Well, I wouldn't say *the wrapper of bygone time* was meaningfully "a phrase" such that you could ask whether you're using it "correctly" or not. Google have indexed *an awful lot of books*, but apparently the three words *"wrapper of bygone"* never occur there even once. I would say there isn't really *any* way to use those words correctly, but it's certainly a question of literary style/creative writing advice, not English as relevant to people wanting to learn the language.

Comment: ...a relatively common (if somewhat informal) usage is [consigned to the dustbin of history](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22consigned+to+the+dustbin+of+history%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Will I repost this question in other stackexchange forum? Which forum, can you please suggest?

Comment: @Man_From_India: It might be a better fit on [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Fumble's *dustbin* phrase certainly fits well, but does carry, for me, the idea that the things were thrown out deliberately.  An alternative might be, "They seem to be (or have become) things of the past (or *of a bygone era*).

Comment: The wrapper?  What's the wrapper?

Comment: Another common idiom that you could use is "lost in the mists of time". But this and the "dustbin of history" are so overused they have become cliche's, and I wouldn't recommend either one for English learners.

Comment: @The Photon: +1 for "lost in the mists of time", but I don't see why learners shouldn't be aware of (and even *use*) such "cliches". We're not running "creative writing" classes here, and the fact of the matter is people still often use both the *dustbin* and *mists* phrases in natural conversation. But unless you move in some very unusual circles, I doubt you'll often hear ***bygone*** these days. *That's* the kind of word learners shouldn't get too interested in.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, why teach the habit of using cliches that learners will have to "unlearn" when they become more proficient, if they could just write or speak directly: "These customs are not observed any more."

Comment: @The Photon: You seem to be implying that "cliches" are inherently undesirable. That might be true in a Lit Crit context, but in natural speech, practically *all* utterances are "metaphoric" to some degree. From that perspective, "cliche" is just an intermediate point between "creative use of language", and "standard idiomatic usage". It's only potentially unwise for a learner to use any given cliched expression if native speakers have abandoned it (i.e. - it sounds dated or archaic).

Comment: OP's initial guess at a metaphor seems to indicate a desire to learn more "literary" or poetic English, and in that context I would recommend against using cliche'd phrases.  Even if we accept we don't know why OP is learning English, I wouldn't recommend getting in the habit of using phrases with limited utility when there are alternatives available. I agree there's no problem using these phrases in speech or informal emails.

Comment: Actually, I think learning these "cliches" is a good thing for learners.  Certainly using a common phrase is preferable to putting words together in a novel but unidiomatic manner.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want to write is that there were some customs (possibly old) that are no longer observed by people possibly because they have been forgotten.

I also assume that by using "**gone into the wrapper of bygone time**" you wanted your text to be a little poetic.

Now to answer you:

You did not find any reference because this is not a known or recorded metaphor in English language. You are the inventor of it. I see no grammatical error in it but at the same time I don't see a practical use of it nor see it getting accepted by English users.

I believe(though I am not sure) that you came up with it when you translated a metaphor used in your local language.

Some good alternatives:

- lost in time
- forgotten in time

Comment: There are some more possible alternatives in the comments.  (You could include them in your answer, if you liked.)